# How to Call localhost service from ATL VC++ BHO

Tags: events, service, bho

From ATL VC++ BHO i want to call `http://localhost:8888` with some post data and receive data back from it. Basically IE extension would need to call HTTP POST request. From BHO code if I inject javascript and there add AJax post call this is not allowed because of cross site restrictions.   Any suggestions on this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make HTTP request directly from your BHO code. Check [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43860/An-Asynchronous-HTTP-Download-Class-for-MFC-ATL-an) for code samples

Answer (score 2):

Thanks,

Following code works for C# BHO :-

```
using (var wb = new WebClient())
                {
                    var data = new NameValueCollection();
                    data["user"] = "D";
                    data["id"] = "E";
                    data["token"] = "token";
                    var response = wb.UploadValues("http://localhost:8888", "POST", data);
                }
```